# Extracting 4-digit number from a string in Selenium IDE - error message

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, substring

I'm trying to build a regex in Selenium IDE that would extract 4-digit number from an input text stored using `storeValue`. The string that gets stored is, for example, `'undergraduate 2016 computer science'`. Extracting the 4-digit number should produce a result of `2016`, reassigned and stored as `year` variable. I tried it in a following way:

```
storeValue | xpath=/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/input[1] | year
storeEval | storedVars['year'].match[0-9]{4}; | year
```

but executing the code produces `[error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement`. Does anyone know how that could be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `storedVars['year'].match(/[0-9]{4}/);`

Comment: Great, it works! Many thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the regex inside the js regex delimiters `/regex/` and again within braces.

```
storedVars['year'].match(/[0-9]{4}/);
```

To do an exact 4 digit match, add word boundaries.

```
storedVars['year'].match(/\b[0-9]{4}\b/);
```